# SSRS Sharepoint online

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sharepoint-online

We have SSRS 2012 and looking to run our reports form Sharepoint 365.  (Office 365 Enterprise E4)

Does anyone know if this is now possible?  I don't think it was at first and when looking into it keep finding conflicting report and nothing definitive.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS for SharePoint Online is available as an external service from [ThorApps](https://www.thorapps.com).
Its called [Reflex Reporting for SharePoint Online](https://www.thorapps.com/reflex-reporting-online-services)!.

Answer (score 0):

Probably better asking this in the SharePoint stack but here is a screen clip/information from the Microsoft site here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx

It shows that SSRS is unavailable in O365 currently.

[image: SSRS SharePoint Online]